# Can I use the Genki Mobile's flamethrowers?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

As part of the GenkiBowl 7 DLC, I was awarded the Genki Mobile, featured in the the PR missions of that DLC pack.

It shows the flamethrowers as equipped when I get in it, with infinite ammo.  However, I haven't ever been able to activate them, despite my best efforts at running down pedestrians.

Is it possible to use the flamethrowers on the Genki Mobile?  Or are they sadly unavailable outside of the "PR" side mission?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can use the flamethrowers on the Genki Mobile.

It takes 4 pedestrians being run over in quick succession in order to activate them.

The 4 red lights on the back of the car will turn green (from left to right) as you run over pedestrians.  Get all 4 to turn green and the flamethrowers will activate.  After a couple of seconds of not hitting any pedestrians, the most recently turned green light will revert back to red (if the flamethrowers haven't already activated).

The flamethrowers only stay active for a few seconds (all 4 lights will countdown and revert back to red),  and will then need to be recharged again by hitting 4 more pedestrians.

[image]